# How to assign the result of an expression to a variable in bash

Tags: bash, syntax, variable-assignment

In following bash script I'm trying to assign a value from a json object to a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

json_data='{"ip":"1.2.3.4", "country_code":"GB", "country_name":"United Kingdom"}'

echo json_data:
echo $json_data

echo country_code:
echo $json_data | jq '.country_code'

echo country_name:
echo $json_data | jq '.country_name'

cc=$json_data | jq '.country_code'

echo cc:
echo $cc

cn=$($json_data | jq '.country_name')

echo cn:
echo $cn
```

Just echoing the expressions works.
Assigning the value of the expressions to variables cc or cn doesn't.

```
$ ./test.sh 
json_data:
{"ip":"1.2.3.4", "country_code":"GB", "country_name":"United Kingdom"}
country_code:
"GB"
country_name:
"United Kingdom"
cc:

./test.sh: line 19: {"ip":"1.2.3.4",: command not found
cn:

$
```

I thought that wrapping an expression in $(...) gave the functionality I need, but that results in an error.

Could anyone advise as to the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that wrapping an expression in $(...) gave the functionality

You did not wrap enough. Wrap the *whole* expression, including `echo`.

```
cn=$(echo "$json_data" | jq '.country_name')
```

Remember to quote variable expansions. Check your script with shellcheck - shellcheck will notify you of many problems.

You can put anything inside `$(...)`, maybe this will clear it:

```
cn=$(
  echo "$json_data" | jq '.country_name'
)
```

Comment: Thank you KamilCuk, that works. For my example data, it works whether $json_data is double quoted or not. Do I not have to concern myself with the fact that $json_data itself contains " characters?

Comment: `$json_data itself contains " characters?` No. But if you do not quote, you have to concern yourself if json_data contains spaces, tabs, newline and `*` and `?` and `[` characters. Try `json_data='{ "value": "   *    " }'; echo $json_data` vs `echo "$json_data"`. As a rule of thumb, quote it.